# Real solution of equations of 2018

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

**Question:**

What can we say about positive real solutions to the equations

$x^{x^{2018}}=2018$ and $x^{x^{x^{... }}}=2018$

**Options:**

1)One exists,other does not (Correct answer)

2)they exist and are same(Wrong)

3)they exist but are different.(Wrong)

**My approach :**

The second infinite power sequence is either 1 or diverges, therefore there is no solution.

**Conclusion:**

*Any solution or guidance on how to approach and solve this problem would enable me to increase my knowledge and others who come across this question *

Comment: $x^{x^{...}}=2018$, we can use this to substitute in the same equation $x^{x^{2018}}=2018$. right?

Comment: yes absolutely correct

Comment: You're wrong about the second series.  This is the famous "power tower" and it converges when $e^{-e} \le x \le e{1/e}$.  You can read about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights  If I recall correctly, the maximum value it converges to is $e^e,$ so nowhere near 2018.

Comment: wow i didn't know that.Thanks for notifying it on this post.That's a really useful addition to my post.

Comment: The upper limit is $e^{1/e}$.  I noticed the typo too late to edit my earlier comment.

Comment: yes i also noticed that right now.

Comment: So why this tower has no solution? If i write $x^{2018} = 2018$ - this seems to me to be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x^{x^{2018}} = 2018 \implies x^{2018 x^{2018}} = 2018^{2018} \\
\implies (x^{2018})^{( x^{2018})} = 2018^{2018} \\
\text{this allows at least one possible solution} \\
\implies (x^{2018}) = 2018  \\
 x = 2018^{1/2018} \approx 1.003778111307819
$$

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comments above, there is no value of $x$ such that the infinite "power tower" converges to 2018.  As to the other problem, taking logarithms twice gives $$\log \log x + 2018 \log x = \log \log 2018.$$

When $x=1$ the left-hand side is $-\infty$ and when $x \rightarrow \infty,$ the left hand side goes to $\infty,$ so by the intermediate value theorem, there is a solution.  If fact, since the left-hand side is clearly an increasing function of $x$, the solution is unique.  (Approximately $1.003777,$ but that's pretty rough.)